# how to post an array with some object when I have an array with id, using angular

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, object

I need your opinion how to post an array with some object.

I have this code:

```
 const selectedJobs = this.ms.selectedItems;
    if (!selectedJobs) {
      return;
    }
    const selectedJobsId = selectedJobs.map((jobsId) =>
      jobsId.id
    );
```

in this case I get all jobId like an array `['618e2ee9', '3ee199b7']`

```
    const payload = [
      {
        jobId: selectedJobsId,
        state: 2,
      }
    ];
```

from payload I get an array with one object that have inside an array with JobsId and state. As below

```
 [
    {
        "jobId": [
            "618e2ee9",
            "3ee199b7"
        ],
     "state": 2
    }
]
```

I should get this response, one array with all objects. all jobs id to be objects:

```
[
    {
       "jobId": "618e2ee9",
        "state": 2
    },
    {
      "jobId":  "3ee199b7",
    "state": 2
    }
 ]
```

Have you any idea please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
    const payload = selectedJobsId.map(job => 
                        { 
                          return {jobId: job, state: 2};
                         });
```

Answer (score 0):

> const desiredArray = selectedJobs.map(job =>
> {jobId:job.id, state:job.state}
> );